# Add a value to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I've just created a new array that is one larger than my previous array and I want to copy the values in my first array into my new one. How do I add a new value to the last index of the new array?

This is what I've tried:

```
public void addTime(double newTime) {
    if (numOfTimes == times.length)
        increaseSize();
    times[numOfTimes] = newTime;
}
```

Comment: Wow, a lot of great answers here. Are you sure **none** of them were of any help?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying to use an object such as `java.util.List` rather than raw arrays.  Then you can just do:
 `times.add(newTime)` and it handles the sizing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you use System.arraycopy function.

```
increaseSIze()
{
   double [] temp = new double[times.lebgth+1];
   System.arrayCopy(times,0,temp,0,times.length);
   times=temp;
}
```

after that you have times array with 1 increased size.

Answer (score 0):

To set a new value to the last index you can do

```
times[times.length - 1] = newTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indices go from `0..n-1`.

`array[array.length - 1]` will address the value at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The last item of an array is always at `myArray.length - 1`. In your case the last element from the times array is `times[times.length - 1]`. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html for more information about arrays.

But more importantly: If you're trying to change the capacity of your array, you are most likely using the **wrong data structure** for the job. Have a look at Oracle's [`Introduction to Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) (and especially the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class if you need an array-like index to access elements).

Answer (score 0):

why wouldn't you want a java.util.ArrayList for this requirement? Practically, there won't be a need managing its size. You just simply do this:

```
 List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
 list.add(newTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28double%5B%5D,%20int%29) if working with arrays is a constraint:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
private void increaseSize() {
   // Allocate new array with an extra trailing element with value 0.0d
   this.times = Arrays.copyOf( times, times.length + 1 );
}
...
```

Note that if you are doing this type array management often and in unpredictable ways, you may want to consider one of the [Java Collection Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) classes such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). One of the design goals of `ArrayList` is to administer size management, much like the JVM itself administers memory management.

I've developed an online executable example [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/771001).